# RTMP Video Streaming using Wowza Media Server on Android Devices

Tags: android, video-streaming, wowza

I'm developing video streaming application for android devices to stream videos to Wowza Media Server using RTMP. For this purpose I've used [this](http://www.walking-productions.com/notslop/2013/01/16/android-live-streaming-courtesy-of-javacv-and-ffmpeg/) method.

The problem with this method is that it is not incorporating publisher name and password to check validity of incoming stream.

Is there any better RTMP streaming method for Wowza Media Server which includes validation of publisher?